# Recovering loaded Varnish config

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I've accidentally copied over my default.vcl and erased my fairly complex configuration. So long as I don't try to reload the configuration or restart Varnish everything is running fine - I'm hoping there's a way to view or "extract" my loaded configuration from Varnish so I don't have to rewrite it from scratch. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may as well login in the admin console ( `varnishadm`) and run `vcl.list` to list all the vcl that are loaded. And then `vcl.show` to display the most recent one.

Vcl list is cleared when varnish service is restarted or stopped.

Comment: This does exactly what I had been looking for, running "vcl.show boot" produces the loaded configuration. Seems like I stumbled upon this file in my grep search, however your method is much cleaner so I'll mark it as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue by recovering my loaded config file using -

```
grep -i -a -B100 -A100 'text' /dev/vda
```

Replaced 'text' with a line of code I remembered from the config.